# Rich Text Editor "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." and internal server error thrown

Tags: richtext-editor

For as long as I can remember, my rich text editor hasn't worked.

[image: rich text error]

At this point I'm not sure whether it's a security issue or a web config issue, but the problem does affect all sites under the same project if that's any help. I am logged in as admin and this is local development. I just tested it in production, and the error does not occur there.

Therefore, my gut tells me that it's some type of a file issue. But any direction is appreciated.

Here's what the log spits out:

> 5916 12:40:17 ERROR Application error.
>   Exception: System.Web.HttpUnhandledException
>   Message: Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown.
>   Source: System.Web
>      at System.Web.UI.Page.HandleError(Exception e)
>      at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoin
>   t, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>      at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, B
>   oolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>      at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()
>      at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
>      at ASP.sitecore_shell_controls_rich_text_editor_editorpage_aspx.ProcessReques
>   t(HttpContext context) in c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Tempor
>   ary ASP.NET Files\root\f5fafede\75924706\App_Web_4an5wvrc.3.cs:line 0
>      at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplica
>   tion.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>      at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& compl
>   etedSynchronously)
>
> Nested Exception
>
> Exception: System.NullReferenceException
>   Message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>   Source: Sitecore.Client
>      at Sitecore.Shell.Controls.RichTextEditor.EditorPage.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
>      at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
>      at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoin
>   t, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>
> 5916 12:40:17 ERROR Error Url: http:/site.com/sitecore/shell/Controls/Rich
>   %20Text%20Editor/EditorPage.aspx?da=core&id=%7B04733BD9-54B4-45F2-8661-EF964BCAA
>   7E6%7D&ed=FIELD98016355&vs&la=en&fld=%7B217FDF39-763D-4E3D-8193-B8929DF02D00%7D&
>   so&di=0&hdl=H98016451&mo&pe=0&fbd=1

In my web.config, I have the default text editor defined as:

`<setting name="HtmlEditor.DefaultProfile" value="/sitecore/system/Settings/Html Editor Profiles/Rich Text Default"/>`

Which should be the default value.

When I look in the core db content editor, the tree does appear to expand as referenced and the files look as though they are all there  (specifically the `/sitecore/system/Settings/Html Editor Profiles/Rich Text Default` folder).

Cheers.

Comment: The last error that starts with `ERROR Exception in alarm clock event subscriber` is not related to your problem. Remove the contents of the `SubmitQueue` folder under `Data` and that error will go away.

Comment: Much appreciated. Your suggestion did work for getting rid of that error. I will update the question to remove that part as it's extraneous to the issue at hand.

Comment: @DmytroShevchenko post that as an answer ;)

Comment: @ZacharyKniebel nah, that was a separate error and a separate fix.

Comment: I have the same error and I've recently upgraded to 8.2. Could you fix it or still an issue?

Comment: I am having the same issue with sitecore 7.2. Any idea to solve this?

Comment: Did you find out why the Query param was missing ? I am facing the same issue currently.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1622)

Answer (score 1):

I have compared your rich text editor request with my local setup. It seems the Sitecore path is missing in the request that you have mentioned. Your request:

```
http:/site.com/sitecore/shell/Controls/Rich %20Text%20Editor/EditorPage.aspx?da=core&id=%7B04733BD9-54B4-45F2-8661-EF964BCAA 7E6%7D&ed=FIELD98016355&vs&la=en&fld=%7B217FDF39-763D-4E3D-8193-B8929DF02D00%7D& so&di=0&hdl=H98016451&mo&pe=0&fbd=
```

My rich text editor's request captured through Fiddler (notice the path):

```
http:/localstepup/sitecore/shell/Controls/Rich%20Text%20Editor/EditorPage.aspx?da=core&id=%7B110D559F-DEA5-42EA-9C1C-8A5DF7E70EF9%7D&ed=FIELD23519447&vs&la=en&fld=%7BA60ACD61-A6DB-4182-8329-C957982CEC74%7D&so**=%2Fsitecore%2Fsystem%2FSettings%2FHtml%20Editor%20Profiles%2FRich%20Text%20Default**&di=0&hdl=H23519458&mo&pe=0&fbd=1
```

Comment: So the question then is, where could I make that change to make the path correct?

Comment: Before this, did you try adding the sitecorepath in it manully & tried accessing it ? was it working ? please confirm.

Comment: I have this same problem in all environments.  Manually placing the path in the query string does not work.  I did notice that all RTE fields that do not have the editor specified in the source field are the ones failing.  If I put a path to a RTE then it all works just fine.  This was always working for us in 8.2 but not in 9.3 for some reason.  Solution, fill out the source field with a path to an editor

Comment: Adding /sitecore/system/Settings/Html Editor Profiles/Rich Text Default path in the source field did it for similar issue I had. This is the answer.